# In mediaElementjs the setSrc method doesnt work when using youtube plugin

Tags: mediaelement.js

In mediaElementjs the setSrc method doesnt work when its using youtube plugin?
This is my code

media.setSrc("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxx");

Now in the definition of setSrc the library does

this.pluginApi.setSrc(mejs.Utility.absolutizeUrl(url));

but this.pluginApi.setSrc doesnt exist when using youtube plugin and html5 player.

Comment: I can confirm that this does happen. Not sure why though

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the `mediaelements` flash video player ([FlashMediaElement.as](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/src/flash/FlashMediaElement.as)) you can see that it does not currently support switching what backs `_mediaElement` after the constructor creates `_mediaElement` as either `VideoElement` or `YouTubeElement`.  This means that if you start the player with a youtube source:

```html
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtu.be/nOEw9iiopwI" />
</video>
```

Then, your `setSrc()` call with subsequent YouTube clips will work just fine... but, you still will not be able to switch back to non-youtube videos.

Currently, the only way to switch back and forth between youtube and non-youtube is to detect the switch on your own and destroy the element that you added `mediaelements` to, create a new one, then call setSrc on the new one.  Not pretty, but it will get the job done.